# What is the best way to design my mysql tables? I need to represent a user with a map of preferences

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am creating a web application that will allow administrators to keep track of users and modify their information and access. Most of the information that needs to be represented about a user is straightforward (name, email, workID, ect) but I am having trouble representing a user's access to applications in our system.

There are applications a user will or will not have access to. The list of applications is growing, so I do not want to hardcode access to application 'x' as xAccess is a Boolean. I currently have a Map where the string is the name of the application and the Boolean is the user's access.

I do not know how to represent this in a MySQL table. How should I go about storing this data? Is this the best way to keep track of this data? I am open to any ideas.

I am creating a web application and I hard coded a typescript class with data inside so I could work on the frontend without worrying about saving data. I currently have this typescript class:

```
export class UserModel {
  userId: number;
  windowsId: string;
  fullName: string;
  role: number;
  roleName: string;
  appAccess: Map<string, boolean>;
}
```

appAccess is my current attempt at representing this data, but I do not know a good way to store it in a MySQL table.

Comment: Seems like a good usecase for role based permissions. At the most basic you would have users that have roles and those roles would have permissions (access to an application, for instance). So you would have a user table, role table, and a permission table; and then a user_role table and role_permission table to maintain the mapping between those three objects. [Kind of like this answer outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016139/best-user-role-permissions-database-design-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You might need three tables:

- users:  user_id, user_name, user_status
- applications:  app_id, app_name
- user_applications:  ua_id, user_id, app_id

So if a user has access to an application then there'll need to be a record in the user_applications table which contains the user's user_id and the relevant application's app_id.