# What is the best way to check if user has permission from another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

Please consider the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Permission]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [UserId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [OptionA] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [OptionB] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)

CREATE TABLE [Product] (
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO [Product] ([Id], [Name])
VALUES ('0DB7F090-D314-438F-94F0-3C9E5D2AA353', 'Product 1')

INSERT INTO [Product] ([Id], [Name])
VALUES ('EB0B3A3C-D24E-4FAE-97FD-A944BED852A7', 'Product 2')

INSERT INTO [Product] ([Id], [Name])
VALUES ('76FFF884-BB9F-4EE6-B6A8-92A39C7C6FB6', 'Product 3')

INSERT INTO [Permission] ([Id], [UserId], [ProductId], [OptionA], [OptionB])
VALUES (NEWID(), '81C669A6-98FA-4BE1-98CF-5BE335819C2E' ,'0DB7F090-D314-438F-94F0-3C9E5D2AA353', 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [Permission] ([Id], [UserId], [ProductId], [OptionA], [OptionB])
VALUES (NEWID(), '81C669A6-98FA-4BE1-98CF-5BE335819C2E' ,'EB0B3A3C-D24E-4FAE-97FD-A944BED852A7', 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [Permission] ([Id], [UserId], [ProductId], [OptionA], [OptionB])
VALUES (NEWID(), '81C669A6-98FA-4BE1-98CF-5BE335819C2E' ,'76FFF884-BB9F-4EE6-B6A8-92A39C7C6FB6', 1, 1)
```

What I would like to do is select all the products a user has access to based on Option A. What I am wondering is this the best approach or is there a better one?

```
SELECT *
FROM [Product]
WHERE [Id] IN (
    SELECT [ProductId]
    FROM [Permission]
    WHERE [UserId] = '81C669A6-98FA-4BE1-98CF-5BE335819C2E'
        AND [OptionA] = 1
)
```

You may assume that there will be many more columns, in fact there might even be 50 columns of options. It will not grow infinitively but it will get a decent amount over time (total is unknown as the application will grow).

I am open to suggestions of a different design for permission table, however if you do please show me how you would select from product based on the permission with your new design.

Comment: Sounds like you should normalize it out into `Permission (UserId, ProductId, OptionId)` and have a separate `Option` table

Comment: I would suggest using [roll based permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46016930/3094533).